# Does the triplet sigma state of a diatomic molecule experience spin-orbit coupling?

Tags: spectroscopy, electronic-configuration, spin

I know that states with spin S=0 in a diatomic molecule have no spin orbit coupling, independent on the value of the projection of the total electronic angular momentum.

I expect the same is true if the absolute value of $\Lambda$ is equal to zero independent on the spin of the diatomic molecule.

Is it correct that a diatomic molecule with a $^3\Sigma$ state has no spin orbit coupling?

Answer (score 1):

Yes I would think so because the projection of orbital angular momentum is zero in forming $\Omega=\Lambda + \Sigma$. This would seem to correspond to Hund's case (b) where $\Lambda =0$ but $S \ne 0$, so no spin orbit coupling (unlike Hund's case (a)(c)(d)). The spin angular momentum remains fixed in space and the molecule rotates under it. If $R$ is the whole body (molecular) angular momentum this couples with the spin so that each rotational level splits into $2S+1$ components and the total angular momentum $J$ takes values from $R+S$ to $R-S$. The splitting is scaled with a spin rotation constant rather than spin-orbit constant but in $^3\Sigma$ there is also a $s_1\cdot s_2$ spin-spin coupling term.

Answer (score 0):

First, I think one needs to specify what you mean when you say that a certain electronic state, e.g. one with $S=0$, "has no spin orbit coupling".

One interpretation might be of the type: the energy of that state is unaffected by the spin-orbit operator. That is, if I start with a Hamiltonian without any spin-orbit operator and then gradually switch it on, the energy of that state is unaffected. In this strict interpretation *all* electronic states are affected by spin orbit, including singlet states.

In a less strict interpretation, we might merely require a weak dependence on the spin-orbit operator. In practice this usually means that, in a perturbation-theory treatment, the first-order effect of the spin-orbit operator is zero. In this sense you a right: in diatomic molecules all singlet states (any $\Lambda$) and all $\Sigma$ states (any multiplicity) have a zero first-order spin-orbit energy shift.

Finally, at a purely empirical level we might disregard spin-orbit completely if it doesn't lead to splitting of the state. If spin-orbit leads only to a (small) energy shift, it may not be experimentally measurable (not by an analysis of energy level positions, at least).

In the specific case of $^3\Sigma^\pm$ states, as I said above the effect of spin-orbit is zero at first order of perturbation, so it can be said that they "have no spin orbit coupling". At higher order, they have non-zero matrix elements with the following terms: $^{3,5}\Sigma^\mp$, $^{1,3,5}\Pi$. If a state with one of these symmetries is energetically close it'll have some effect on the $^3\Sigma^\pm$.